# Different pod CIDR for different deployment Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-networking

I am working on a project where I need to launch a particular deployment with a specific CIDR range. Is there any way i can do this ?

I need these CIDR ranges for different deployments.

For example:

1. Deployment 1 - Have 10 replicas running with CIDR 10.10.10.0/24
2. Deployment 1 - Have 10 replicas running with CIDR 10.10.11.0/24

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by using Calico's IPPool.

1. install kubernetes with calico.
2. you create a IPPool, copy the below Yaml content in a file.

```
apiVersion: projectcalico.org/v3
kind: IPPool
metadata:
  name: pool1
spec:
  cidr: 192.168.0.0/18
  ipipMode: Never
  natOutgoing: true
  disabled: false
  nodeSelector: all()
```

and apply this above yaml using the following command

```
calicoctl create -f pool1.yaml
```

Now deploy any service like this

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
      annotations:
        "cni.projectcalico.org/ipv4pools": "[\"192.168.0.0/18\"]"
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.14.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Apply the above yaml using

```
kubectl apply -f nginx.yaml
```

Check the ip of running pods using

```
kubectl get pods -o wide
```